# Link two positions of an object into a single position

Tags: javascript

I receive in this way the object

```
const tests = [
        {id: 0, vencimiento: "231216000000"},
        {id: 0, monto: "99000"},
        {id: 1, vencimiento: "230117000000"},
        {id: 1, monto: "198000"},
        {id: 2, vencimiento: "230217000000"},
        {id: 2, monto: "297000"},
    ];
```

And I want to combine the positions with the same id

```
const resultado= [
     {id: 0, vencimiento: "231216000000", monto: "99000"},
     {id: 1, vencimiento: "230117000000", monto: "198000"},                             
     {id: 2, vencimiento: "230217000000", monto: "297000"},
];
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Always try to share what you tried, no matter how small, for better response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` and return a plain object, 
then use `Object.values()` to get the result you wanted:

```js
const tests = [
    {id: 0, vencimiento: "231216000000"},
    {id: 0, monto: "99000"},
    {id: 1, vencimiento: "230117000000"},
    {id: 1, monto: "198000"},
    {id: 2, vencimiento: "230217000000"},
    {id: 2, monto: "297000"},
];

const res = Object.values(tests.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if(!acc[curr.id]) {
    acc[curr.id] = {...curr}
  } else {
    acc[curr.id] = {
      ...acc[curr.id],
      ...curr
    }
  }

  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(res);
```

[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) 
[Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Comment: What a beautiful use of reduce.

Comment: Thanks! I really looked for the solution a lot, your response really help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const tests = [
  { id: 0, vencimiento: "231216000000" },
  { id: 0, monto: "99000" },
  { id: 1, vencimiento: "230117000000" },
  { id: 1, monto: "198000" },
  { id: 2, vencimiento: "230217000000" },
  { id: 2, monto: "297000" },
];

const newTests = []
for (let index = 0; index < tests.length; index += 2) {
  const arr = tests[index]
  const { monto } = tests[index + 1]
  newTests.push({ ...arr, monto })
}

console.log(newTests)
/* OUTPUT
[
  { id: 0, vencimiento: '231216000000', monto: '99000' },
  { id: 1, vencimiento: '230117000000', monto: '198000' },
  { id: 2, vencimiento: '230217000000', monto: '297000' }
]
*/
```

### How it works

You can deconstruct objects by using the `{ }` when declaring the new variable. You can reconstruct it again using the spread operator `...` with `arr` to combine it with `monto`.

Answer (score 1):

In cases where number of elements is changing `reduce` function is great choice

```
tests.reduce((p,n) => {
    if(p.map(t => t.id).includes(n.id)) {
       let i = p.findIndex(t => t.id === n.id);
       p[i] = {...p[i],...n}
       return p;
    } else {
       return [...p,n]
    }
}, [])
```

Result:

```
0: {id: 0, vencimiento: "231216000000", monto: "99000"}
1: {id: 1, vencimiento: "230117000000", monto: "198000"}
2: {id: 2, vencimiento: "230217000000", monto: "297000"}
```